# Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException (Admob)

Tags: android, admob

This is not a duplicate question.

There's been a new wave of crashes of my App due to Admob. I implemented everything correctly, I don't know what the issue is, please help me out.

Crash Report

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.appname/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult + 1788(Instrumentation.java:1788)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity + 1512(Instrumentation.java:1512)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult + 3877(Activity.java:3877)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult + 767(FragmentActivity.java:767)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult + 3828(Activity.java:3828)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult + 754(FragmentActivity.java:754)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity + 4158(Activity.java:4158)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity + 4126(Activity.java:4126)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.a + 74(m.java:74)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.l.a + 9(l.java:9)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.render.ar.a + 8(ar.java:8)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.u.P + 7(u.java:7)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.l.P(l.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ao.a + 70(ao.java:70)
       at pb.onTransact + 3(pb.java:3)
       at android.os.Binder.transact + 385(Binder.java:385)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfm.zza + 20(zzfm.java:20)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzk.showInterstitial + 37(zzzk.java:37)
```

manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.app_name">

   ...

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
    >

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="admob_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:theme="@style/TranslucentTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme" />

    ...


</application>
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'

    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

progaurd-rule.pro

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.*.* { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

Affected Android Operating System Versions:

from Android 4.0 to Android 7.0, as of now. The most popular crash error coming from android 5.1

Comment: Your proguard might be stripping that activity out of your final build. #1 show us `proguard-rules.pro` #2 unzip your apk file and look to see what's included

Comment: my progaurd rules have been added. @Blundell

Comment: FYI version `18.1.0` of the Ads dependency is out https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup not sure if that will help

Comment: @Blundell i have tried it out and it is breaking badly on android 4.4.2  I reported the bug - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/Pwf-CARw6Sw

Comment: Not the best answer but a hacky answer could be to add `-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }` in your proguard file